# What is the difference between appShell and universal in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, universal, app-shell

I need server side rendering in my angular application to get the benefit of both `SEO` and boosting the load time of my app but I got confused with `appShell`

As I read, I found that `Angular Universal` can solve my problems, so what `appShell` is for?